# Team Foundation Server - Shared Binding

Tags: tfs

Presuming the following scenario:-

File 1 exists in Project A -> local path = C:\ProjectA\FileLocation\

File 2 exists in Project B -> local path = C:\ProjectB\Filelocation\

Does anyone know if it is possible to do the following in TFS:-

Bind File 1 and File 2 such that BOTH their local paths are, for instance, C:\Program Files\FileLocation\

I know this is not ideal however this is a large codebase that has been migrated to TFS control from another source control application and I am looking for a quick solution at the moment.

Comment: what version of Tfs are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in TFS2010 this is not possible.
If you try to Map `$/ProjectB` to a spot that already houses `$/ProjectA` TFS will refuse to proceed: 
[image]

*Sidenote*: Why proceed like that? For example, if ProjectA = ProjectB, simply choose one over the other & have all solutions point to the survivor.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to accomplish what you want with the structure you have.  You may have no choice but to restructure your code now.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really prevents you from referencing something from Project B in a solution in Project A, even Team builds can map folders from other Team Projects.  It's not a nice solution, but it could work in the short term.

However, best practices suggest creating a 3rd team project for the shared code and only referencing binaries from it.  You can then manage versions using Team Build and a Package Manager like NuGet/OpenWrap.

Sure it means you need two versions of VS open if you're editing core libraries and your project at the same time, but it does help remind people that shared libraries are shared and can effect other people.